# Finding homotopy classes

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have just started to read algebraic topology. I am following the "Topology" books by Munkres. Author denotes $[X,Y]$ as the set of classes of maps of $X$ into $Y$. In exercises of 'Homotopy of paths',

$3(c)$: If $Y$ is contractible $[X,Y]$ has a single element for any $X$.

$3(d)$: $[X,Y]$ has a single element if $X$ is contractible and $Y$ is path connected.

My attempt: In the case of $3(c)$, let $f,g$ be two continuous function. I want to show they are in the same equivalence classes i.e, $\exists F:X\times [0,1]\to Y$ a continuous function such that  $F(x,0)=f(x)$ and $F(x,1)=g(x)$. Since $Y$ is contractible it will be path connected. So for fixed $x\in X$ we get $f(x),g(x)\in Y$ and moreover we can join $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ by a path i.e, $\exists h_x:[0,1]\to Y$ a continuous function such that $h_x(0)=f(x)$ and $h_x(1)= g(x)$. Now we define $F(x,t):=h_x(t)$. Now I think this $F(x,t)$ is our desired continuous function. Is anything is wrong in my argument?

May be I am missing something because I am not using the full strength of contractiblity of $Y$! Moreover if my argument is correct then in $3(d)$ we don't need $X$ to be contractible. So certainly my argument is wrong. Kindly can you point out where I am going wrong and clarify my doubts?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are many choices of paths from $f(x)$ to $g(x)$. Why is $F$ independent of that choice, or why is the resulting function $F$ at least continuous?

Comment: @anomaly for the case of $3(c)$, let $h_x$ and $h'_x$ be two path joining  $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. Then $h_x*\overline{h'_x}$ be a continuous loop with base  at $f(x)$. Since $Y$ is contractible this loop is nulhomotopic. Then any hint?

Comment: There's no reason why that function should be a continuous function of $x$. Instead, use the homotopy equivalence $Y \to *$ and the fact that $[X, *]$ is trivial. (If you have results on the homotopy invariance of $[X, Y]$ (in, e.g., the category of based spaces), then most of the problem is trivial.)

Comment: @anomaly I am not able to follow. Can you please explain bit more?

Comment: What part of that is unclear?

Comment: @anomaly If I understand correctly then since $Y$ is contractible then any path joining $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ will be in the same equivalence class. Is it the meaning of  "the homotopy equivalence $Y\to *$"? Why is $[X,*]$  trivial?